# Problem compiling nginx on Solaris 10

Tags: nginx, solaris-10

My setup as below

```
# export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/ccs/bin
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --user=webservd --group=webservd --with-http_stub_status_module --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl --with-debug --with-pcre=/usr/local/bin
```

and i get error code as such when i execute make

```
# make
make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/export/home/myhome/nginx-0.7.63'
cd /usr/local/bin \
        && if [ -f Makefile ]; then make distclean; fi \
        && CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe " \
        ./configure --disable-shared
/bin/sh: ./configure: not found
make[1]: *** [/usr/local/bin/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/myhome/nginx-0.7.63'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That initial `cd` to `/usr/local/bin` looks very strange; are you building it in the global /usr tree?

It looks as if it's cd:ing to the wrong directory, for some reason. Look in the referenced Makefile (`objs/Makefile`) and try to figure out why.

UPDATE: It seems the problem is that it's trying to *build* the PCRE library. If you have it pre-built, that seems like an odd decision. [This blog post](http://kovyrin.net/2006/08/30/nginx-redhat-pcre-problem/) suggests using the `--with-cc-opt="-I /usr/include/pcre"` option to point out to the configure script where you have headers for PCRE, might be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you for the blog post link solution, it work fine now :)